# Is there an easier way of making an embed via command? | discord.py REWRITE

Tags: python, discord.py

I am setting up a new command which I would like to go into a nice embed. It works, if every argument is 1-word long. However, for colours like `dark red` and `dark magenta`, it counts "dark" as the colour, "magenta" as the title then everything after that as the value.

The only way I thought I could get it to work is where the command has you do something like `k!embed <colour>, <title>, <value>` all separated by commas but I don't know of a way to do this. I TRIED googling it, but most likely due to a lack of terminology found nothing. Also, adding in more asterisks didn't seem to help... that was my last desperate effort.

```py
@client.command(name='embed',
                aliases=['e'],
                pass_ctx=True)
async def embed(ctx, colour, name, *, value):

    # making paramater match dictionary
    colour = colour.lower()
    colour.replace(' ', '_') 

    # checking if colour is valid
    if colour not in colours:
        await ctx.send('Invalid colour')
        return
    else:
        colour = colours[colour]
        # sets colour
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color = colour()
            )  
    # adds other paramaters
    embed.add_field(name='{}'.format(name), value="{}".format(value), inline=False)

    # final product
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    print('Embed executed\n- - -')
```

As I mentioned, typing something like `k!embed dark magenta title this is the value` gets lost completely, and I would prefer something like `k!embed dark magenta, title, this is the value` or something to that affect. Thank you!

edit: for context, this is the `colours` dictionary and title typo:

```py
colours = { "red" : discord.Color.red,
            "dark_red" : discord.Color.dark_red,
            "blue" : discord.Color.blue,
            "dark_blue" : discord.Color.dark_blue,
            "teal" : discord.Color.teal,
            "dark_teal" :discord.Color.dark_teal,
            "green" : discord.Color.green,
            "dark_green" : discord.Color.dark_green,
            "purple" : discord.Color.purple,
            "dark_purple" :discord.Color.dark_purple,
            "magenta" : discord.Color.magenta,
            "dark_magenta" : discord.Color.dark_magenta,
            "gold" :discord.Color.gold,
            "dark_gold" : discord.Color.dark_gold,
            "orange" :discord.Color.orange,
            "dark_orange" :discord.Color.dark_orange
            }
```

Comment: You  might be able to write a greedy converter that consumes that could form a color name until it has a complete color name.  It's not possible to control where the argument parser splits the input

Comment: I saw something about greedy in the docs, and don't quite understand it. Also, if i can't choose the split, is there something like `k!embed dark red "title" value goes here` i could do, where "dark red" has this greedy converter thing, title is whatever is in the speech marks and value keeps going on anyway?

Comment: `k!embed "dark red" title value goes here` should work with the setup you have.  I'll have to set some time aside later to see if there's a way of using greedy converters for this, I don't know much about how they work internally yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you, if there is an easier way of doing embed through command, I'd be happy to give that a go! I just made this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom converter that should be able to recognize colors even if they are not quoted by consuming another word from the unparsed arguments:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Converter, ArgumentParsingError
from discord import Color, Embed

class ColorConverter(Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        argument = argument.lower()
        if argument in ('dark', 'darker', 'light', 'lighter'):
            ctx.view.skip_ws()
            argument += "_" + ctx.view.get_word().lower()
        if not hasattr(Color, argument):
            ctx.view.undo()
            raise ArgumentParsingError(f"Invalid color {argument}")
        return getattr(Color, argument)()

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, color: ColorConverter, *, text):
    await ctx.send(embed=Embed(color=color, description=text))
```

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'ArgumentParsingError'`, i assume this is needed, and i cannot import it?

Comment: That's odd. You  could raise some more generic exception instead, it will just be less clear what happened.  You might try making sure that your discord.py is up to date and that everything is spelled correctly.  Make sure your're trying to import it from `discord.ext.commands` and not `discord` too.

Comment: It might be my version, I am running 1.0.0 and the latest stable one is 1.0.1